# Debug is not working in ASPNET 7.0.100-preview7 when dotnet 6 is installed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rider, .net-7.0

I can run `dotnet watch` and I can `Run` my ASP.NET core application, but if I try debugging, I get the error message below. I have .NET 7 sdk installed (otherwise `dotnet watch` and `Run` in my app wouldn't work either)

```
/home/timmy/Repos/myaspnetapp/src/Application/bin/Debug/net7.0/Application 
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /home/timmy/Repos/myaspnetapp/src/Application/bin/Debug/net7.0/BlazorDebugProxy/BrowserDebugHost.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '7.0.0-preview.5.22303.8' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/

The following frameworks were found:
  6.0.8 at [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
```

**More info**

- I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04 and Rider 2022.2.1, but it seems VS Code has the same issue so I think it's a dotnet issue.
- I have dotnet6 installed in `/usr/lib/dotnet`, subfolder `dotnet6-6.0.108`
- I've had dotnet7 in multiple different folders to see if that would make any difference
- In Rider the `Toolset and Build` path for `.NET CLI executable path` is `/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet7-7.0.100/dotnet` and the MSBuild path is that same folder but `sdk` subdirectory

It's worth noting that debugging a .NET 7 console project works fine, but not ASP.NET core.

I may uninstall .NET 6 to see if that would help but my hopes are a bit low after wasting hours trying to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All kinds of issues are tracked in https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues so you should use that to connect to Microsoft engineers directly.

Comment: Created issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43420